# Get online current time in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

What is/are the disadvantages if I run this command and get the current time from the server every second?

```
fetchCurrentTime() {
    fetch(this.getApiUrl())
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(resp => {
        const currentTime = resp.dateString;
        this.setState({currentTime})
      })
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get current online time using this API 
https://timezonedb.com/api

OR

`new Date().getTime();`